# How to load a panel with a form that is specified in a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, load, panel

How can I load a panel with a form who's name is specified in a variable?

for example:

```
Private Void LoadNewForm(string FormName)
{
 pnlForm.Controls.Add((Form)Formname);
//or
Form f = new (FormName)
 pnlForm.Controls.Add(f);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use reflection or make a Facade with input a string ans result a Form. (or do both)

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Name");
Type type = assembly.GetType("Name.FormName"); <<  fully-qualified name of the type
Form f = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```